# Current date in email template openerp?

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

How to add current date in email template so that current date will be showed in the mail? Also how can we change the date format to be displayed?

Comment: which email template you are talking ?

Comment: its about email template in openerp

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`email_templates` use 'jinja' template engine. The bad news for lazy people like us is that `jinja` doesn't support inline python. You have only access to variables passed to the template at render time.

One of this variable is `object` and represents the object you attach to the template, let say `res_partner`. What you can try is to extend `res_partner` and add a field which calculates the current date. Something like this:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, Model

class res_partner(osv.Model):
    """Inherit res.partner to add a generic field that can be used
       to in email templates."""
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    def _get_now(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
        from datetime import datetime
        return datetime.now()

    _columns = {
        'current_date_time': fields.function(_get_now, type="char",
                                             method=True, store=False)
    }

res_partner()
```

Now you should be able to put in your template this:

```
${object.current_date_time}
```

I didn't test it. Let me know if it works if you try it.

Comment: Hi @Andrei! May be is too late to let you know the result, but I tried  it, and when I create the template through the interface, the field current_date_time is not available (I guess this is because it's not stored in the database). I tried to write directly the variable and when I send the email is as if I had written nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenERP/Odoo email template,

You could add javascript to compute your current date.

```
<script language="javascript">
   var today = new Date();
   document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=today;
 </script>
```

and call this value by using 
***`<p id="time"></p>`***

Note: I obtained this info from another question.  [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994748/display-the-current-date-and-time-using-html-and-javascript-with-scrollable-affe)