# Display the current date and time using HTML and Javascript with scrollable effects in hta application

Tags: javascript, css, html, hta

I have the below java-script to display the current date in the given format Mon Jun 2 17:54:28 UTC+0530 2014 in a hta(html application), now I want to make this appear in a way like Welcome the current date of my system:  **Mon Jun 2 17:54:28 UTC+0530 2014** and this text should be a having scrollable affects for eg: one moving from right to left.

I tried to use the below tag to get a scrollable text but how can I call this java-script variable in the `<marquee>` tag so that I get the today's date and time also as a part of the scrollable affects but it is not working for my HTML page.

Kindly let me know how to rectify this issue

**HTML CODE:**

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" bgcolor="yellow" loop="-1" width="30%">
  <i><font color="blue"><strong>Welcome</strong> Today's date is : </font></i>
</marquee>
```

**JAVASCRIPT TO DISPLAY THE CURRENT DATE AND TIME:**

```
 <script language="javascript">
 var today = new Date();
 document.write(today);
 </script>
```

Comment: Avoid using `<marquee>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: but then what tag do you suggest to use for the scrollable effects?

Comment: Anything you want `<p>`, `<span>`, `<div>`, ideally all animation should be done by CSS / Javascript

Comment: Apart from the <marquee> element being non-standard (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) the <font> element has been deprecated since HTML 3 days.

Answer (score 14):

### Method 1:

---

With `marquee` tag.

**HTML**

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" bgcolor="yellow" loop="-1" width="30%">
   <i>
      <font color="blue">
        Today's date is : 
        <strong>
         <span id="time"></span>
        </strong>           
      </font>
   </i>
</marquee>
```

**JS**

```
var today = new Date();
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=today;
```

**[Fiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/n2XB6/63/)**

---

### Method 2:

---

Without `marquee` tag and with `CSS`.

**HTML**

```
<p class="marquee">
    <span id="dtText"></span>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.marquee {
   width: 350px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background:yellow;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   color:blue;
   font-size:18px;
}

.marquee span {
   display: inline-block;
   padding-left: 100%;
   text-indent: 0;
   animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```

**JS**

```
var today = new Date();
document.getElementById('dtText').innerHTML=today;
```

**[Fiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/L8b1e7mr/22/)**

Comment: i need to display only data day year i need to skip time zone

Comment: You are **not** supposed to use `marquee` anymore. Because it is obselete now. See [this mdn doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

Comment: Asked for `marquee`, that's the reason answered with `marquee`. And also given an alternate way to do.

Answer (score 4):

This will help you.

### Javascript

```
debugger;
var today = new Date();
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = today
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/V5bKt/1/)

Comment: i need to display only data day year i need to skip time zone

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    var today = new Date;
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML= today.toDateString();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

HTML:

```
<div id="para1"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = formatAMPM();

function formatAMPM() {
var d = new Date(),
    minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes(),
    hours = d.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0'+d.getHours() : d.getHours(),
    ampm = d.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am',
    months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
    days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
return days[d.getDay()]+' '+months[d.getMonth()]+' '+d.getDate()+' '+d.getFullYear()+' '+hours+':'+minutes+ampm;
}
```

Result:

```
Mon Sep 18 2017 12:40pm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="clockbox" style="font:14pt Arial; color:#FF0000;text-align: center; border:1px solid red;background:cyan; height:50px;padding-top:12px;"></div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.